# How to use custom typings in JS project

Tags: visual-studio-code, typescript-typings, checkjs

I'm working in an Electron project with `checkjs: true` set in my `jsconfig.json` and have created a file with custom typings in `ProjectRoot/typings/index.d.ts`.

I'd like to have those typings available in all JS files. Unfortunately I have to reference them manually:

[image]

Without the manual reference, it won't recognize the type:

[image]

My Project structure looks like this:

[image]

Here's the content of **typings/index.d.ts**:

```
interface LauncherItem {
    name: string,
    icon: string,
    cmd: string,
    args: string,
}

interface AppConfig {
    items: LauncherItem[],
    appIconSize: number,
}
```

And **jsconfig.json**:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "checkJs": true
    },
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "include": [
            "./typings/index.d.ts"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*.js",
        "*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Not sure if the explicit `typeAcquisition` and include of `*.d.ts` is usually necessary. They're just a result of my tests but obviously didn't work...

Comment: did you manage with this? if you remember :)

Comment: No, I have not found a way around this. Please keep me posted if you do ;)

Comment: Short update: I just removed the manual `reference path` from the js file and the `typeAcquisition` in `jsconfig.json` and it still recognizes the correct type for `AppConfig`. So it seems like this had been an issue in VSCode and had been fixed in one of the updates since Jun...

Comment: Thanks for the update